# Raspi2 and ArchLinux MongoDB installation

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi2, archlinux

everyone. I just installed ArchLinux on Raspi2 success but I observed mongodb is not available at repos. Certainly, since few weeks, it's unsopported at 32bits. Well, I downloaded:

```
mongodb-3.0.7-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz
```

and

```
v8-3.16-3.16.8.1-2-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz
```

from http://tardis.tiny-vps.com/aarm/repos/ and installed with pacman -U *package*, but trying exec mongodb I get below mistake:

```
mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.59.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

First ¿how could I install mongodb in arm 32bits? and ¿what's the error means?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

After installed

`boost-libs-1.59.0-3-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz`

package downloaded from mentioned page, I get next:

> mongo: symbol lookup error: mongo: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitERKSsPKNS_10RE_OptionsE

I not surrender...